# Does Adaline say why she has to leave the city at the beginning?

Tags: dialogue, the-age-of-adaline

Can you tell what Adaline says to Ellis why she is leaving the city at the beginning of *The Age of Adaline*?

I am not talking about the time when she runs away from his parents' house, but about the beginning. She mentions that she will need to move out, but did she say why (did she explain to Ellis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> She mentions that she will need to move out

Actually, she doesn't say that she **needs** to move out...just that she *IS* moving away.

but **NO** she never actually explains *why* she was proposing to move away.

The closest to an explaination he gets (via his doorman passing a message) is...

> "Please, tell him I understand if he doesn't want to see me. I'm here just to say I'm sorry, and that my... my life has been unbelievable, since longer than he can imagine,
>   and I just... I was emotional the other day, and... Now that I realize how
>   incredibly kind to me he's been, and I... I... I've just been too stupid to accept it, and... I know better now, and... and that's why I want to tell him how sincerely sorry I am."